# How do I get help.start() to show package and user manual information?

Tags: windows, r

I'm running R 3.1.1 (64-bit) on Windows 7, and R is up-to-date and freshly restarted.  If I type help.start(), I get the expected help page (e.g.,

```
http://127.0.0.1:15729/doc/html/index.html
```

) to open in Firefox.  Clicking on most links works; I get the expected page.  Clicking on Packages and on User Manuals fails.  For the former, I get a browser window at

```
http://127.0.0.1:15729/doc/html/packages.html
```

with "Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection".

For the latter, I get a browser window at

```
http://127.0.0.1:15729/doc/html/UserManuals.html
```

with "Error in vignettes[i, "PDF"] : subscript out of bounds".

c:/R/R-3.1.1/doc/html contains an 81-line packages.html but no UserManuals.html.

This seems true whether I run help.start() out of ESS or out of RStudio.

If I start RStudio in an admin account and run help.start(), the main help page shows up in the RStudio Help window.  Clicking on Packages now works, but clicking on User Manuals still fails with the same message as above.

As you can see above, R is stored in a directory with no spaces in the PATH name, and packages seem to be stored in c:/R/R-3.1.1/library.

Any pointers on how to fix either problem?

Comment: Have you tried `help.start(update = TRUE)` ?

Comment: > help.start(update = TRUE)
    Making 'packages.html' ...Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
    In addition: Warning message:
    In gzfile(file, "rb") :
      cannot open compressed file 'C:/R/R-3.1.1/library/BayesTree/Meta/package.rds', probable reason 'Permission denied

There is such a file in BayesTree, and permissions as displayed by Dired seem the same for this package and the ones immediately before and after it in an alphabetical list.

Comment: Fix your permissions problem.

Comment: BondedDust is correct.  I had four obsolete packages that I found by running find . -name package.rds -exec head {} \;  > /dev/null.  When I removed them, that problem went away.  (I still don't know why the User Manuals are missing under Miscellaneous Material.)  BondedDust, if you want to post an answer, I'll mark it.